# Play video overlay over video not working in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to play video over another video using ffmpeg. When i am trying to play video from starting then overlay video plays. But if i try to overlay video from n seconds it doesn't work

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i overlay.mp4
-filter_complex [1:v]scale=920:920[out],[out][0]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t\,4\,8)'[out]
-map [out] output.mp4
```

If i change `between(t\,4\,8)` to `between(t\,0\,4)` then overlay video works normally. It is not working for `between(t\,4\,8)`. Please help how to solve it

Comment: This community is for programming questions. Your question belongs on a site like superuser.com

Comment: Show the complete console output from your command. Without it we can only guess.